# ¿Problema con archivo JSON?

Tags: java, android, html, json

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de como crear una gáleria en android con glide y la información esta en un archivo .json el código luce así

```
[{
"name": "Deadpool",
"url": {
    "small": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/small/deadpool.jpg",
    "medium": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/medium/deadpool.jpg",
    "large": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/large/deadpool.jpg"
},
"timestamp": "February 12, 2016"
},
{
"name": "Batman vs Superman",
"url": {
    "small": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/small/bvs.png",
    "medium": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/medium/bvs.png",
    "large": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/large/bvs.png"
},
"timestamp": "March 25, 2016"
}]
```

pero al cambiar la direccion de las imagenes por ejemplo por alguna imagen mia android studio me tira este error

> ```
> > 11-01 15:12:13.358 26978-26978/com.example.android.ejemplo
> > E/MainActivity:    Error: org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type
> > java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
> ```

el archivo .json se tiene que "enlazar" con algún archivo html?? o porque el error?, espero su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Podrias proporcionar tu código con tu dirección de imagenes, si quieres tapa la url, por que parece que tienes un problema en la creación del JSON que tu estas generando, pudiera ser confundir el , por ;

Comment: Agrega completamente el contenido de tu .json, si usas la misma url entonces tal vez tu archivo quedo corrupto cuando agregaste otra url de imagen.

Comment: ¿Que usas para serializar y recuperar los archivos json? Porque si lo haces manualmente puede que este ahí el problema, tenes varias librerías como Gson que tienen métodos de reflexión que te facilitan el trabajo

Comment: El error es clarísimo: Android espera un `JSONArray`,  justo el tipo de objeto que pones al principio de la pregunta, pero el servidor está respondiendo con otra cosa, en este caso por la referencia a `<html>` en el error, se puede intuir que que responde con un archivo HTML o con contenido con esa etiqueta. El código de servidor debe estar programado para devolver **únicamente** lo que la petición enviada desde Android espera: **un `JSONArray`**, que se caracteriza por empezar con `[` y terminar con `]`. Es diferente de un `JSONObject` que empieza por `{` y termina por `}`.

Comment: lo mas probable es que este devolviendo un error, talvez un error 500, la unica forma de verlo es pantalla es usandon `postman` o  `insomnia`

Answer (score 1):

Revisando tu  error:

> Error: org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String
>   cannot be converted to JSONArray

hace referencia a un `"<html>"`, posiblemente el error es que la url es incorrecta, asegura proporcionar realmente un url con contenido `.json.

Otra razón es que probablemente al editar tu archivo no esta correctamente formado.

Answer (score -2):

podrias intentar esto:

```
[{
    "name": "Deadpool",
    "url": [{
        "small": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/small/deadpool.jpg",
        "medium": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/medium/deadpool.jpg",
        "large": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/large/deadpool.jpg"
    }],
    "timestamp": "February 12, 2016"
}, {
    "name": "Batman vs Superman",
    "url": [{
        "small": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/small/bvs.png",
        "medium": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/medium/bvs.png",
        "large": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/large/bvs.png"
    }],
    "timestamp": "March 25, 2016"
}]
```

creo que que faltan los corchetes para armar en arreglo en esta parte:

```
"url": {
    "small": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/small/deadpool.jpg",
    "medium": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/medium/deadpool.jpg",
    "large": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/large/deadpool.jpg"
},
```

espero te ayude este cambio.

Comment: El JSON está bien formado.

Lo puedes probar aqui https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: en este caso el JSON no esta bien formado, es correcta la respuesta en cuanto la estructura del JSON, le hacían falta los [].